# add property to onet.xml sharepoint 2010

Tags: sharepoint-2010

I am wondering if there is somebody who can help me with this probelm.
I want to add a property to onet.xml of my custom webtemplate. so that if you create a site from this web template the site will contain the property.
is that possible? Thank you.

Comment: What property do you want to add?

Comment: I am trying to add workspaces or subsite under my web sites (which can be a spweb or spsite) so I need to add property to the one.xml file of the original web sites to know where I am when I create sub sistes. now I am using the url which is not good to check where I am to do som controls. when I create the subsite i can add the property but the original site has no property. I don't want to use feature. thanks

Answer (score 1):

Please refer this... it contains some information about [onet.xml](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms432370.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

This is also a very useful link describing how to reference properties from your custom web part. http://aarebrot.net/blog/2008/11/loading-custom-web-parts-inside-your-onet-xml/

The link explains how v3 format looks like, if you haven't noticed it is different from using v2:

```xml
<webParts>
  <webPart xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/WebPart/v3">
    <metaData>
      <type name="Client.Publishing.Intranet.WebParts.ClientStoryRotator,Client.Publishing.Intranet.WebParts, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=320209e28e1f8058" />
      <importErrorMessage>$Resources:cmscore,WebPartImportError;</importErrorMessage>
    </metaData>
    <data>
      <properties>
        <property name="Title" type="string">$Resources:Client.Publishing.Intranet.Lists.Articles,list_Stories_Title;</property>
        <property name="Description" type="string">$Resources:Client.Publishing.Intranet.Lists.Articles,list_Stories_Description;</property>
        <property name="ListName" type="string">$Resources:Client.Publishing.Intranet.Lists.Articles,list_Stories_Title;</property>
        <property name="WebName" type="string">$Resources:Client.Publishing.Intranet.SiteTemplates,webpart_Library_Url;</property>
        <property name="Width" type="string">$Resources:Client.Publishing.Intranet.SiteTemplates,webpart_Stories_Width;</property>
      </properties>
    </data>
  </webPart>
</webParts>
```

Comment: Please add the relevant text from the link into the answer body, links may die.